# Mailto body with query link in it

Tags: html, url, mailto

I am making a "share" link that is working fine but the text I am adding to the body has a url with a query in it so the body stops at the ampersand. Example:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=Checkt&body=http://localhost:80/test.org/test/test-Countdown/?city=test&eventdate=20160301&description=Lorem%20ipsum">
```

will add this to the body:

Event Link: http://localhost:80/teste.org/test/test-Countdown/?city=test

It stops at the `&` after the first query.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: You might have to UrlEncode the URL.

Comment: That is encoded @HaukurHaf

Comment: Only the Lorem Ipsum part is encoded.  This is the entire URL encoded:  http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A80%2Ftest.org%2Ftest%2Ftest-Countdown%2F%3Fcity%3Dtest%26eventdate%3D20160301%26description%3DLorem%20ipsum

Comment: Not sure it will work, but worth a shot.